# calculate days excluding weekends and public holidays in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Form to calculate performance of employees on the assigned task. performance calculation is excluding all weekends and public holidays for Hong Kong.How to do this in Asp.Net MVC?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you trying to do this in javascript, or C#? Please only tag the language you're trying to achieve this in.

Comment: It seems that you can get a [list of public holidays](http://www.1823.gov.hk/common/ical/tc.json) from [the government site](http://www.1823.gov.hk/eng/blog/calendar.aspx), and then you just need to add in weekends.

Comment: You can contribute to https://github.com/martinjw/Holiday as adding Hong Kong public holiday handling and then use this library.

Comment: well, most people in Hong Kong work also on weekends and public holidays without pay!